# Determine Loaded Assemblies

Tags: .net, winforms, dll, assemblies

How can I determine all of the assemblies that my .NET desktop application has loaded?  I'd like to put them in the about box so I can query customers over the phone to determine what version of XYZ they have on their PC.

It would be nice to see both managed and unmanaged assemblies.  I realize the list will get long but I plan to slap an incremental search on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyAppDomain
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    Assembly[] loadedAssemblies = ad.GetAssemblies();

    Console.WriteLine("Here are the assemblies loaded in this appdomain\n");
    foreach(Assembly a in loadedAssemblies)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(a.FullName);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**PowerShell Version:**

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

Answer (score 2):

Either that, or System.Reflection.Assembly.GetLoadedModules().

Note that AppDomain.GetAssemblies will only iterate assemblies in the *current* AppDomain. It's possible for an application to have more than one AppDomain, so that may or may not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();` will do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

For all DLLs including unmanaged, you could pinvoke EnumProcessModules to get the module handles and then use GetModuleFileName for each handle to get the name.

See http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/psapi.EnumProcessModules and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx (pinvoke.net does not have the signature for this but it's easy to figure out).

*For 64 bit you need to use EnumProcessModulesEx*