# Understanding DLL hell

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have trouble understanding the mechanisms by which Visual Studio resolves dependencies to .NET dlls. In some `.csproj` file, I have some dependency as follows.

```
<Reference Include="SomeDependency,
                    Version=SomeVersion,
                    Culture=neutral,
                    PublicKeyToken=SomePublicKeyToken,
                    processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>SomeHintPath</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

However, the `HintPath` pointed to an invalid path, yet Visual Studio was able to build and deploy the project as desired, apparently taking the dll from *somewhere else*. In my case, this wasn't a major problem as the final result was as desired, but I ultimately do not understand by which mechanism dependencies to .NET dlls are resolved.

How can I find out which dll is actually referenced when building a Visual Studio project? What are the permitted locations for dlls?

Comment: Does this answer your question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972/in-what-order-are-locations-searched-to-load-referenced-dlls)

Comment: @KevinWallis Yes, sort of, thanks for the reference. However on second thought, it does not; basically the answers are stating that "it depends".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to determine all loaded assemblies and also check the path of them:

```
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
Assembly[] loadedAssemblies = ad.GetAssemblies();

Console.WriteLine("Here are the assemblies loaded in this appdomain\n");
foreach (Assembly a in loadedAssemblies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.FullName);
}
```

from the post ([Determine Loaded Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959/determine-loaded-assemblies))

And here is the documentation of "How the Runtime Locates Assemblies"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Accepted as definite answer since apparently the link is the most comprehensive source; however I hoped that things would be less complex.

Comment: @Codor yeah its quiet complex