# DLL Loading rules

Tags: dll-search-path

I want to know what search rules are used when LoadLibrary specifies absolute path for a known dll that is already loaded.

Some details on what I am doing:
- I am using a "known dll" for installation of a driver.
- I am redistributing this dll and copying this dll to app installation folder
- I am calling Loadlibrary to load this DLL and also specifying absolute path to DLL.

We want installer to user DLL from APP folder (our version).

Thanks, Neetu

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009408/understanding-dll-hell

Answer (score 0):

With absolute path and existing DLL file there are no "search rules", i.e. no search. It is OK to have DLL in app folder (not shared with other).